# Crystal Report Windows Forms Viewer : Object Reference not set to an instance on an object

Tags: vb.net, exception, crystal-reports

I am working with a Crystal Reports in Vb.Net Forms application. A huge report that consists of 10-12 Sub-Reports,there are many formulas used in this report, sometimes this report shows "Object Reference not set to an instance on an object" I can't figure out, I have handled exceptions as well. When I click to "Next Page" button it shows below dialog.

[image: Error]

I can't figure out why its happening.
read many blogs, some says, its formula error, some says, "Mouse Move" error.

Below is the code I have added, i will check now

```
 Private Sub CrystalReportViewer1_HandleException(ByVal source As _
Object, ByVal e As CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.ExceptionEventArgs) _
Handles CrystalReportViewer1.HandleException

'Label1.Text = e.Exception.ToString();
'Here I will trap.

End Sub
```

Below is the stack trace I have found by applying above code for exception:

```
Source:CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Message:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
ST:   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.get_IsLoaded()
at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.NonHTTPCachedReportSource.GetReport(RequestContext  context, Boolean bAddToCacheWhenCreated)
at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.LocalReportSourceBase.GetPage(PageRequestContext pageReqContext)
at CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.MainReportDocument.GetPage(PageRequestContext context)
```

Comment: It should be something to do with the data you're passing. When the data is being manipulated through the CR formulas, it ends up with exception. Try checking the values being passed and for every value that can be NULL,do add some vlaidations

Comment: As soon as I Press Mouse Down or Up key, It pop-up this MessageBox.

Comment: meaning the formula is not being able to execute!

Comment: There was other thing I found today which caused that dialog box to appear, I set my system on standby by left opened that report in report viewer, when I came and hit mouse key, the exception box appeared, seems the object or viewer have lost the reference. anyone could suggest ?

Comment: @Nadeem_MK : Sir, this error I have received from Log. That machine running Windows 7- 32-bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking a solution for this, 
anyway i found the issue with my problem and so i am posting it here.

My report had a subreport and the its links where not set properly from the main report. In this scenario when i try to set only the parameters of main report and try to load the report, i was getting this object reference error.

So either link the subreport parameters to main report parameter or may be you can try setting the sub report parameters too. I have set the subreport parameters to link to the main report parameters and it works.